# How to get order of selected value of a dropdown in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="10">Mr</option>
<option value="20">Mrs</option>
<option value="30">Ms</option>
<option value="40" selected>Dr</option>
<option value="50">Prof</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the order of selected option which is 4 if initial value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.index()` function to trace its order,

```
$("#myselect option:selected").index() + 1 
// index() will return a 0 based index so added a 1 to it.
```

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Glad to help!.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.index()`

```
$('option').index(':selected'); //will return 3 as index is 0 based property
```